# MapServer: apply a symbol to certain data?

Tags: mapserver

I have a shp file which contains some points. Each point has a "POINTTYPE" attribute which contains text.

Is it possible to apply a different symbol basing on this attribute? For example, if pointtype is "streetlamp" use a square icon, if it is "tree" use another one, etc...?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the final mapfile

```
LAYER
    NAME bla
    TYPE POINT
    GROUP bla
    DATA "bla.shp"
    STATUS OFF
    CLASS
      EXPRESSION ('[pointtype]' = 'streetlamp')
      STYLE 
        SYMBOL 'circle'
        SIZE 8
        COLOR 255 0 170
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        ANTIALIAS TRUE
      END
    END
    # Other classes can go here, they will cumulate
END
```

Comment: I think the correct syntax is EXPRESSION ([pointtype] = 'streetlamp')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about

[LAYER](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html)
CLASSITEM
[CLASS](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/class.html#class)
[EXPRESSION](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/expressions.html#expressions)

in Mapserver documentation

HTH
/Nicklas

**edit:**

example but with polygons in the documentation:

http://mapserver.org/tutorial/example1-3-map.html#example1-3-map

What can be tricky is to get the symbols right.
Is that the problem?

Comment: I am missing just a few rep points to vote this down. If documentation was clear enough to understand this I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: hmm, since you don't say anything about what part of the concept you don't understand I tried to point you to the parts of the map-file that handles those things. I will add a link to an example from the documentation in my answer.

Comment: Much more useful now :) I just missed the EXPRESSION parameter and how to bind it on a point's property, which turned out to be: EXPRESSION ('[pointtype]' = 'streetlamp') inside the CLASS definition. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ok, didn't it work with CLASSITEM?

Comment: @Palantir - threatening to down vote someone who took the time to answer your question is not in my opinion a very good way to thank someone or build a good community here.

Comment: @DavidF: Sorry, I am community member on Stack Overflow since over a year with almost 6k reps, I know how things should work, and I don't accept your criticism. Answers which are nothing more than a RTFM (like the original one was, just 4 links to the manual) deserve a downvote in my opinion. I upvoted & accepted as soon as the answer got a bit more useful.

Comment: Good that the fourth link to the same manual made you happy :-). I have almost 10 friends at Facebook and 500 bonus points at my Disney Land VIP-card, so I guess I should be the man to get the answer right at last :-)

Comment: @Palantir:  Please accept my humble apologies.  I failed to make true deference to your impeccable credentials and only judged you based on your behavior and my observations of community norms.  I am but a mere speck of dust.  Now that the community is aware of your mad skilz and moderate accumulation of virtual currency in a different online community, I hope that they will provide you with all of the respect here that you fully deserve.

Comment: One thing is to provide a link to a specific relevant example, another thing is to link to half of the manual. I cited rep points only to clear the fact that I am an old community member and that I am aware of stackexchange etiquette.